# Meaning of '>>' in Python byte code

Tags: python, virtual-machine, bytecode

I have disassembled the following python code

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n ==4:
        print('hi')
    return n * 2
```

and the resulting bytecode

```
 2        0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          6 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
          9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE         16

3        12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         15 RETURN_VALUE        

4     >> 16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
         22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        32

5        28 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
         31 RETURN_VALUE        

6     >> 32 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         35 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
         38 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         41 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        52

7        44 LOAD_CONST               4 ('hi')
         47 PRINT_ITEM          
         48 PRINT_NEWLINE       
         49 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 52)

8     >> 52 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         55 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
         58 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
         59 RETURN_VALUE
```

What do the '>>' symbols in the above bytecode stand for?

Comment: Looks like targets for `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`. See this article: [Understanding Python Bytecode](http://security.coverity.com/blog/2014/Nov/understanding-python-bytecode.html)

Comment: @self: No, a right shift is `BINARY_RSHIFT` or `INPLACE_RSHIFT`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are jump targets; positions earlier `*JUMP*` bytecode jumps to when the condition is met.

The first jump:

```
         9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
```

jumps to offset 16, so at offset 16 the output has a target `>>`:

```
4     >> 16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
```

From the [`dis.disassemble()` function docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.disassemble) names each column:

> [...]
>
> 3. a labelled instruction, indicated with `>>`,

and the [`dis.findlabels()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.findlabels):

> Detect all offsets in the code object code which are jump targets, and return a list of these offsets.